# Parsing XML with nodes containing underscores

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, identifier, e4x

How do I parse an XML document that contains nodes where underscores exist?

```
<some_xml>
    <child_node>
        <child width_info="" height_info="" />
    </childnode>
</some_xml>
```

I tried this:

```
for each (var item:XML in Environment._XMLData.some_xml.child_node.child){
    trace(child.@width_info);
}
```

But that does'nt seem to work. I can't change the XML either because its from a third party. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the underscore is not the reason, it’s a legal character throughout XML.

Comment: have you tried (simply for the sake of debugging) using a similar xml file with no underscores? You most likely have another problem. As Dormilich said, underscores are valid in xml tag/field names

Comment: Yep. I already did a test, with the exact same code above and it doesnt work. Seems to be the underscore because once i take it away, it works.

Comment: It's worth observing that the opening tag for the child node has an underscore, but the closing tag doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that some_xml is your root node, so you don't need to include that.

This should work:

```
for each (var item:XML in Environment._XMLData.child_node.child){
    trace(item.@width_info);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing to remember is that .NODE and .ATTRIBUTE are shortcuts for .child("NODE") and .attribute("ATTRIBUTE") respectively (as per [Traversing XML structures (c/o the livedocs)](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=13_Working_with_XML_08.html)

So I would think that something along the lines of the following would work (the code is untested but the theory should be sound).

```
for each (var item:XML in Environment._XMLData.child("child_node").child){
    trace(child.@width_info);
}
```

Note, if the attribute isn't defined you'll get a run time error - you can prevent this by either doing:

```
if(child.hasOwnProperty("width_info"))
    trace(child.@width_info);
```

or just use attribute

```
trace(child.attribute("width_info"));
```